# In org-mode refresh the numbers in a numbered list

Tags: org-mode

I am in Org Mode and I have a numbered list.

```
1. Hello
2. World
3. How
4. Ya
5. Doing?
```

I remove the first entry to get the following.

```
2. World
3. How
4. Ya
5. Doing?
```

Is there a shortcut to refresh the numbering, and to end up with the following?

```
1. World
2. How
3. Ya
4. Doing?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With point anywhere in the list, press <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>.

It runs `org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c` which does many things depending on the context, see its [documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/doc.html#org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c).